# Which of arithmetic, geometric or harmonic mean is the most appropriate in this case?

Tags: signal-processing, average

I have a software that periodically detects tempo out of an audio signal and I would like to compute the *average* tempo out of all the generated values.

Example:

```
253.8171
253.8171
253.8171
126.7117
126.7117
126.7117
126.8721
126.8721
126.8721
126.8426
etc ...
```

The approximative tempo of the source is 126 but as you can see beginning the detection there are false positives.

I've tried to compute the arithmetic, gemoetric and harmonic means out of these values:

Arithmetic mean : 127.8833534

Geometric mean : 127.6208897

Harmonic mean : 127.4547577

Those values all sound great to me as they're close to each other ...

Could some math expert shed some light on which type of mean is the most appropriate ?

Comment: An arithmetic or geometric mean would be most appropriate. Beyond calculating means, you might want to filter your data. I.e., if you expect that the entire stream is close to a certain tempo, then I would add a step that retrospectively throws out data points that look wildly divergent from the calculated mean after some period of time.

Comment: Do you think you can elaborate a bit more in an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a first draft of a data filter:

After you have collected the first $N$ data points, call them $x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$, you calculate a mean, call it $m_N$ and some standard deviation $s_N$. Then look back at the the data points and if any of them don't satisfy a test of not being noisy, $|x_j - m_N| < Cs_N$, for a constant $C > 0$, throw them out of the data set. Now recalculate the mean.

You could tune the algorithm to find the best values of $N$ and $C$ for your application either manually or with machine learning.

There are also more sophisticated approaches. See, e.g., http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Laro01-swing.pdf

Comment: This is likely to keep me busy for a while, thank you !

Comment: Good luck! Real data is nearly always tricky!

Comment: The document you've provided is really helpful, thanks !